# angular 6 ngx chips not displaying properly

Tags: html, angular, tags, angular6, ngx-chips

So I'm using `ngx-chips` in my current projects and I saved my objects in an array so I can use the following example:

```
<div>
        <h3>Tags within an autocomplete component (clear on blur events)</h3>
        <tag-input [ngModel]="['@item']"
                   [clearOnBlur]="true">
            <tag-input-dropdown [focusFirstElement]="true" [autocompleteItems]="autocompleteItems">
            </tag-input-dropdown>
        </tag-input>
    </div>
```

For some reason, what I get is an empty field that does not work, instead of what was shown in the example below:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<tag-input [ngModel]="selectedExercises" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                   [clearOnBlur]="true">
          <tag-input-dropdown [focusFirstElement]="true" [autocompleteItems]="exercises">
          </tag-input-dropdown>
      </tag-input>
```

where `selectedExercises` is an empty array where I want to store the tags I select and `exercises` is an array of objects where I want to choose from

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Kamil sadly no

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Comment: yes it seems to be working now, but I'll be using it for another feature. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case the issue was simply resolved by adding modules to `shared.module.ts` to `exports` section:

```
@NgModule({
...
exports: [...,
    TagInputModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule],
```

and the code itself is basically copy-paste from [github example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-chips-example)